# Referenceing an exposure in dbt

Tags: dbt

I am new to using exposures. I want show more than 1 step downstream. Is it possible to make an exposure that depends on another exposure? How do you reference it? I tried this but it doesn't work. It says there is no node Step1:

```yaml
  - name: Step1
    depends_on: 
      - ref('MyTable')

  - name: Step2
    depends_on: 
      - ref('Step1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported today. Exposures are leaf nodes in the directed, acyclic graph.

However there is a [dbt-core GitHub issue](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/2835) today lists what you're asking for as a potential new feature:

> **exposures that depend on other exposures**:
>
> one exposure for each Mode query / Looker view, one exposure for the
> dashboard that depends on those queries / views

Until then, the best you can do if you have a DAG like: `table_A -> exposure1 -> exposure2`, then you could restructure it like:

```
         exposure1
        /
table_A
        \
         exposure2
```

IMHO, documenting only `exposure1` is sufficient, but sounds like you'd like more.